# How to parse complex XML to a long format data frame in R

Tags: xml, r, xml-parsing

I tried to parse XML to R data frame.

```
xml.text <- 
  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<recordGroup>
    <period>60</period>
    <record>
        <dateTime>01102015000000</dateTime>
        <field>
            <id>Equipos.0CR02-1.AE</id>
            <value>34.405000</value>
        </field>
        <field>
            <id>Equipos.0CR02-1.API</id>
            <value>160.794000</value>
        </field>
    </record>
    <record>
        <dateTime>01102015001500</dateTime>
    <field>
      <id>Equipos.0CR02-1.AE</id>
      <value>38.309000</value>
    </field>
    <field>
      <id>Equipos.0CR02-1.API</id>
      <value>152.800000</value>
    </field>
  </record>
</recordGroup>'

library(XML)
xml <- xmlParse(xml.text)
indata <- xmlToDataFrame(getNodeSet(xml, "//recordGroup/record")[1])
```

I get it work only with one record. And the result is that it creates a table with two columns (*dateTime* and *field*) and only one row. All text between tags below *field* are joined together:

```
    dateTime                                                      field
1 01102015000000 Equipos.0CR02-1.AE34.405000\nEquipos.0CR02-1.API160.794000
```

As the *dateTime* is for both field structures it is needed to get a long format table structure as this:

```
    dateTime            id               value
1 01102015000000 Equipos.0CR02-1.AE    34.405000
2 01102015000000 Equipos.0CR02-1.API  160.794000
3 01102015001500 Equipos.0CR02-1.AE    38.309000
4 01102015001500 Equipos.0CR02-1.API  152.800000
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Your xml is a little messed up, but we can fix it:

```
library(XML)
xml <- xmlParse(xml.text)
xmlout <- do.call(rbind, xpathApply(xml,'//recordGroup/record', xmlToDataFrame))
```

which gives you:

```
            text                  id      value
1 01102015000000                <NA>       <NA>
2           <NA>  Equipos.0CR02-1.AE  34.405000
3           <NA> Equipos.0CR02-1.API 160.794000
4 01102015001500                <NA>       <NA>
5           <NA>  Equipos.0CR02-1.AE  38.309000
6           <NA> Equipos.0CR02-1.API 152.800000
```

you can then clean it up using `tidyr` and `dplyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

xmlout %>% fill(text) %>%
           na.omit

            text                  id      value
2 01102015000000  Equipos.0CR02-1.AE  34.405000
3 01102015000000 Equipos.0CR02-1.API 160.794000
5 01102015001500  Equipos.0CR02-1.AE  38.309000
6 01102015001500 Equipos.0CR02-1.API 152.800000
```

Comment: Thanks. It's working for one record set. But for more sets xmlout only give one result. I'm editing my question to add one record set more.